# Why jest or jsdom does not support contenteditable

Tags: typescript, jestjs, jsdom

I have a test case:

```
test('get html element content editable value', () => {
  // arrange
  const id = 'foo';
  document.body.innerHTML = `<div id='${id}' contenteditable="true">1</div>`;

  // act
  const elem = document.getElementById(id);

  // assert
  expect(elem.isContentEditable).toBe(true);
  expect(elem.contentEditable).toBe('true');
});
```

- **Expected**: true, true
- **Actual**: undefined, undefined

I get the same output if I use `new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html')` in TypeScript. But it works fine on the TypeScript playground. Moreover it works if I use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12mtjzw9/).

Does it mean `jsdom` or `jest` has limited support of the `contenteditable` property?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a known issue since 2016: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1670

And it's still not implemented in 2020.

Answer (score -1):

As Maxim pointed out, this is a known issue with no intention to be fixed. If you are merely interested in the `contentEditable` property, you can add the following in your test setup as a workaround:

```
// JSDOM does not support Element.contentEditable
// https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1670
const jsdom = new JSDOM(...)
Object.defineProperty(jsdom.window.HTMLElement.prototype, 'contentEditable', {
    get: function() {
        return this.getAttribute('contenteditable')
    }
})
```